# Get Calendar by name from Outlook using Powershell script

Tags: python, powershell, outlook, calendar, office-automation

I used a powershell script (found it in the Google)to get the calendar from exchange outlook and called the script in python.[[image: powershell script]]

But somehow I'm not able to get the calendar that I want, I'm just getting the default calendar every time I run the code.

I tired this solution from the internet and add it to my powershell script

```
$myNewFolder = $folder.Folders("name_of_the_calendar")
$myNewfolder.items
```

But is does not work, cuz the folder is the default calendar and the default calendar has not inner calendars to call using $folder.Folders

[image: calendars]

How can I get the other calendars as shown in the Image?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a PowerShell guru, but the Outlook object model is common for all programming languages, so you may understand the required sequence or property and method calls in the following VBA macro:

```
Sub ListAllSharedCalendars()
    Dim olPane As NavigationPane
    Dim olMod As CalendarModule
    Dim olGrp As NavigationGroup
    Dim olNavFld As NavigationFolder
    Dim olCalFld As Folder
    
    Set Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set olCalFld = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set olPane = Application.ActiveExplorer.NavigationPane
    Set olMod = olPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)
    Set olGrp = olMod.NavigationGroups.Item("Shared Calendars")
   
    For i = 1 To olGrp.NavigationFolders.Count
        Set olNavFld = olGrp.NavigationFolders.Item(i)
      
        Debug.Print olNavFld.DisplayName
    Next

End Sub
```

The [NavigationPane object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.navigationpane) represents the navigation pane displayed by the active `Explorer` object. Use the `Modules` property to return a `NavigationModules` object that represents the collection of navigation modules contained by the navigation pane. Use the `DisplayedModuleCount` to return the count of `NavigationModule` objects currently displayed in the navigation pane and the `CurrentModule` property to return or set the currently selected `NavigationModule` object.

You may also find the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method helpful, it returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user.